# Allow login of a specific users from specific IP address Keycloak

Tags: authentication, authorization, keycloak, ip-restrictions

I have a Keycloak server with many users and the  account console or login endpoint (../auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth) is public on the Internet.
Now I want to restrict some of my users' login access to this client based on their IPs.

For example if I have 2 users with the username of "test1" and "test2", test1 and test2 only can login successfully if and only if they logged in from 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2, respectively.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can solve these problems?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should implement your own authenticator using spi

Comment: @Abhijeet Thanks for your response. Is there any example that can help me figure it out?

Comment: Refer https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_auth_spi_walkthrough

Comment: this reference only talks about how to write your own custom spi, you can refer this to create your own according to your requirement